# Horizontal sliding site using jQuery

Tags: jquery, slide

I am trying to make my website slide horizontally using jQuery, however my knowledge of jQuery is very limited, and I was wondering if somebody could tell me if I am going along the right track!
I have commented at each stage what I want the code to do, here is my code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var totalSections = $('section').length;
// get width of viewport
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
// set a number to be zero
var total = 0;
// start looping through sections
$('section').each(function() {
    // set a variable to be width multiplied by total
var leftValues = (viewportWidth * total);
    // set current section to have the width of the value of variable 'leftValues'
        $(this).css("width" , //I can't finish this line?
    //add 1 to total
            $('section').each(function() {
        var newTotal = (total + 1);
    });
});
```

I have no idea if my code is correct so far!
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I don't think you need to loop through the sections. All your sections will be wrapped into an element that will get the width as: `$('section').length * viewportWidth`
After that you'll need a navigation that will animate the `left` property of the wrapper. 
Ex: want to go to a page: `left: -(viewportWidth*slideIndex)`

Comment: Ok... I'm going to have a play around and see if I can get it to work! Thank you! :-)

Comment: You could give jQuery scrollTo plugin a try, if you don't mind a small code overhead: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/. I used it for several scrolling sites.

Comment: I've almost managed to fix it, it is now horizontal sliding but a little broken! Unfortunately I'm not allowed to use a plugin, I'm an apprentice, and this is my first project, with strict guidelines - no plugins! But thank you!

Comment: I managed to finish the line i couldn't finish, and it almost works... $(this).css('left',leftValues + 'px'); ...just if anybody was interested!